# The specified type member 'Date' is not supported in LINQ to Entities. DbFunctions.TruncateTime()

Tags: entity-framework, linq, entity-framework-6, entity-framework-4

```
Question question = 
         db.Questions
           .Where(q => DbFunctions.TruncateTime(q.Day.DayDate) == DbFunctions.TruncateTime(DateTime.Now.Date))
           .Where(q => q.Order == id)
           .FirstOrDefault();
```

When I try to run the above statement, I get the following error:

> The specified type member 'Date' is not supported in LINQ to Entities

I thought that `DbFunctions.TruncateTime()` method would solve this problem as suggested in many posts I have seen, however I still get the error. I also tried to just apply the method to the database value but I still get the same error.

```
Question question = 
         db.Questions
           .Where(q => DbFunctions.TruncateTime(q.Day.DayDate) == DateTime.Now.Date)
           .Where(q => q.Order == id) 
           .FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: try ti use just : ``DateTime.Now`` instead of ``DateTime.Now.Date``

Comment: hey @Sajid tried that, same error

Comment: What is the type of `q.Day.DayDate` and  `q.Day` ?

Comment: @SelimYıldız DateTime

Comment: @SelimYıldız I tried that originally, thats whats in the question. I have tried both:
DbFunctions.TruncateTime(q.Day.DayDate) == DateTime.Now.Date and
DbFunctions.TruncateTime(q.Day.DayDate) == DateTime.Now

Comment: You need to declare variable before LINQ,  I've added [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60228770/5519709) pls check

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pull `DateTime` into variable before LINQ:

```
var dateOfNow = DateTime.Now.Date;

Question question = 
         db.Questions
           .Where(q => DbFunctions.TruncateTime(q.Day.DayDate) == dateOfNow)
           .Where(q => q.Order == id) 
           .FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: I thought the issue was with the date from the db.... anyway working now. Thanks